# How to use PowerShell to parse IIS logs files

Tags: iis, powershell, log-files

I am looking for samples on how to parse IIS log files.  I'm  just getting started, and rather than search for site, I want personal recommendations about sample sites, sample code or a good book to get started down this learning path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it be easier to work with [LogParser](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I am familiar with LogParser, I heard you can use PowerShell for parsing logs as well, need some samples to get started.

Answer (score 0):

When I don't have logparser available, I've had luck with Select-String like in the example from http://mohundro.com/blog/2006/11/06/find-in-files-with-powershell/ Select-String uses regular expressions by default, so it is very powerful.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | Select-String "text to search for"
```

I've also used the [WebAdministration Module for Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471(WS.10).aspx) to find the right log directory for the sites.